# Why is the table alias 'a' highlighted in pgAdmin 4 for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Why is the table alias 'a' below highlighted in pgAdmin for PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT a.description, 
    b.store_address 
FROM sales a 
    INNER JOIN stores b
    USING(store)
WHERE b.store_address ILIKE '%Mason City%'
;
```

[image: pgAdmin query screenshot]